# Why does spark data frame show different results?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

This statement outputs partitionID and number of records in that partition:
`data_frame.toDF().withColumn("partitionId", spark_partition_id()).groupBy("partitionId").count().orderBy(asc("count")).show()`

```
+-----------+-----+
|partitionId|count|
+-----------+-----+
|          3|   22|
+-----------+-----+
```

This statement outputs number of partitions:

`logger.warning('Num partitions: %s', data_frame.toDF().rdd.getNumPartitions())`

```
WARNING:root:Num partitions 4
```

Shouldn't they both be same in num of partitions? First result shows only one partition and second result says there are 4 partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Spark actually created 4 partitions but 3 are empty.

```
logger.warning("Partitions structure: {}".format(dynamic_frame.toDF().rdd.glom().collect()))


 Partitions structure: [[Row(.....), Row(...)], [], [], []]
```